# Send POST data in perl

Tags: perl, post, authentication, lwp

login.html

```
 <form method="POST" action="login.php">
 <input type="text" name="username">
 <input type="password" name="password">
 <button class="_sdf3">Login</button>
 </form>
```

login.pl

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use LWP::UserAgent;
 my $username = "admin";
 my $password = "pass2321";
 my $url = "http://127.0.0.1/login.html";
 my $ou = new LWP::UserAgent;
 my $req = $ou->post($url,{ username => $username , password => $password , });
 my $code = $req->code;
 if ("$code" eq "302"){
 print "Username And Password OK";
 }else{
 print "Username And Password BAD";
 }
```

When I run `login.pl` i will see `Username And Password BAD` but the data is right!!

I want to fix this problem while using `<button class="_sdf3">Login</button>` in login.html

Comment: Always include `use strict; use warnings 'all';` at the top of your Perl scripts. LWP::UserAgent doesn't have a `code` method, so `$ou->code` doesn't make sense. You meant `$req->code`, which calls the `code` method on your [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) object.

Comment: ...but I'm guessing this isn't the the code you're actually using, since what you've shown would die with the error `Can't locate object method "code" via package "LWP::UserAgent"` before ever reaching the `else` block.

Comment: @toolic Thanks my bro now it is working , but i want to login with https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/

Comment: can you write a simple script to login with https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/

Comment: @Programmer That's not how [so] works. I would recommend taking a [tour] and reading [ask] so that you know what the expectations are.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting to `login.html` but you should be posting to `login.php`.